# Can't rename a file name

Tags: linux, bash, character-encoding, rename, mv

I have a small bash script that download and rename files. The problem is with some gibberish not standard characters that bash can't understand.

for example:

```
�������� ���� ���'�-2.jpg
```

my bash

```
while read line; do
 if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
  NEW_FILENAME=$(echo "$line" | uniconv -encode Russian-Translit |  uniconv -encode Latin | tr -d '\[\]\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\?\'')
  mv "$line" "$NEW_FILENAME"
 fi
done <<< "$FILES_TO_CONVERT"
```

Comment: Doesn't it work? Try adding -r option to your read command: `read -r line`.

Comment: Are you saying that some file names in `$FILES_TO_CONVERT` are gibberish, or that the script is generating some gibberish file names?

Comment: Some file names are gibberish

Comment: Have you tried `rename` instead of `tr`? `rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' *.jpg`. `rename` is a Perl script to rename multiple files. Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but quite helpful sometimes.

Comment: It might be that these filenames contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you delete those characters with something like :
    `sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]//g'`